# How can I upgrade Laravel 4.2 to 5.4 directly?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

Everyone..
I have large laravel project as version 4.2.
For latest version, I am upgrading this into 5.4
So If someone have rich experience , I 'd like you to help me Conceptually.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to go one by one to reach to 5.4 with no possibility to skip any particular one between… Just go through the upgrade process on the official website.

Comment: You can go @slick's advice or fresh install and get only the controllers, views, models and assets and put it there because laravel 5.* is in diffrent file structure.